# Skipping dependency execution of a disabled task in Gradle?

Tags: dependencies, gradle

Is it somehow possible to *not* execute the dependencies of a task when that task will be skipped?

In the example below, I'd like `jar` (and the dependencies of `jar`) to *not* be executed if a server is already running when executing `runServerTests`. The server would in this case be started by another process.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task startServerIfNotRunning(dependsOn: jar) {
  onlyIf { isServerNotRunning() }
  ...
}

task runServerTests(dependsOn: startServerIfNotRunning) { ... }
```

I'd rather not add an `onlyIf` to the `jar` task, since other tasks that always should be executed may be depending on that one. The `jar` task also has dependencies of its own.

Comment: I don't know the answer here, but if your server depends on the jar, and the jar is out of date why wouldn't you want to restart the server? If the jar is up to date and all it's dependencies are up to date then it doesn't cost you that much time as the jar task is not performing any actions...

Comment: While you do have a point, we do have a lot of sub-projects so it takes about 15-30 seconds to do a complete "recompile" even if everything is up to date. I would like to get rid of this time if possible. Most of the time the server will be up to date.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624391/how-to-set-onlyif-for-dependencies-of-gradle-task/18877504#18877504

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the desired behavior, you have to exclude the task from the task execution graph, rather than skipping its execution. You can do this with `-x` from the command line or programmatically with `gradle.startParameter.excludedTaskNames << "..."` or `gradle.taskGraph.useFilter { task -> ... }`.

Comment: Right, thanks. I'm guessing this must be done in the configuration phase?

Comment: Yes. In the execution phase, the task execution graph can no longer be changed.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Could you explain in more detail or point to detail on the second method you mentioned?

I cannot find "userFilter" in the related docs http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/index.html?org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html

Comment: See `org.gradle.execution.TaskGraphExecutor.useFilter`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like

```
task startServerIfNotRunning(dependsOn: jar) {
    if (isServerNotRunning()) {
        enabled = false;
        dependsOn = [];
    }
}
```

The if statement us evaluate in configuration phase and the dependent tasks are removed. I have summarized this in [Skipping Gradle Tasks](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/12/skipping-gradle-tasks.html) with code and output. Take a look.

Comment: This however has one drawback, and that is that `isServerNotRunning()` will be called in Gradle's configuration phase every time, not just when this task will be executed.

Comment: No, the code in your example is executed in the _configuration phase_, and in this phase all tasks (in the current project) are always configured. The tasks are not always executed, but that's not what I'm saying. I've verified this in Gradle 2.2.1, which is the latest version as of writing.

Comment: You are right, that is a drawback. Verified it with older versions too. I take back my previous comment.

Comment: Excerpt from the above link:  
_> **Note** : One important point to note is `onlyIf` is executed during execution phase and by that time gradle has figured out what all tasks it needs to run. Skipping a single task will not skip the task the skipped task depends on. **We need to add skipping logic in configuration phase**._