# How to set `onlyIf` for dependencies of Gradle task?

Tags: gradle

I would like within a Gradle file to get a list of dependencies of a task in order to add an `onlyIf` clause to them (such that branches of task dependencies can be turned off -- related to [Skipping dependency execution of a disabled task in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214865/skipping-dependency-execution-of-a-disabled-task-in-gradle)). How can this be done?

For example:

```
def shouldPublish = {
    def propertyName = 'publish.dryrun'

    !project.hasProperty(propertyName) || project[propertyName] != 'true'
}

subprojects {
    publish {
        onlyIf shouldPublish
        // the following doesn't work;the gist is that publish's dependencies should be turned off, too
        dependencies {
            onlyIf shouldPublish
        }
    }
}
```

Then, on the command line, one could:

```
gradlew -Ppublish.dryrun=true publish
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you give an example?
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html#getAllTasks()

Comment: @Ethan, I've added more details.

Comment: How about using `--dry-run`? Apart from that, [Skipping dependency execution of a disabled task in Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214865/skipping-dependency-execution-of-a-disabled-task-in-gradle) already explains all possibilities.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, this might be a possibility. I'm trying to do this in Jenkins. If the Gradle task is able to evaluate environment variables in the options field, things should work out fine.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, why doesn't the `dependencies` block above not work?

Comment: Why would you expect it to? There is no such syntax/feature as `dependencies { onlyIf shouldPublish }`. When run, this will probably resolve to `project.dependencies { publish.onlyIf shouldPublish }`, and will effectively be the same as saying just `onlyIf shouldPublish`.

Comment: I expect `dependencies` to accept a function that's evaluated for each of the dependencies. That expectation may be incorrect, but that's my expectation. Why should that expectation surprise you? What about the model of the DSL am I not understanding correctly? FWIW, I find, IMO, inconsistencies with the DSL. For example, what I wrote above compiles just fine but `project.dependencies` does not. This may point to something I'm not grokking about the DSL.

Comment: I think I see where my misunderstanding is. I was under the impression that `dependencies` referred to task dependencies. Now I'm starting to think they refer to project dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The following works:

```
def recursivelyApplyToTaskDependencies(Task parent, Closure closure) {
    closure(parent)

    parent.dependsOn.findAll { dependency ->
        dependency instanceof Task
    }.each { task ->
        recursivelyApplyToTaskDependencies(task, closure)
    }
}

def shouldPrune = { task ->
    def propertyName = "${task.name}.prune"

    project.hasProperty(propertyName) && project[propertyName] == 'true'
}

/*
 * Prune tasks if requested. Pruning means that the task and its dependencies aren't executed.
 *
 * Use of the `-x` command line option turns off the pruning capability.
 *
 * Usage:
 *   $ gradlew -Ppublish.prune=true publish # won't publish
 *   $ gradlew -Ppublish.prune=false publish # will publish
 *   $ gradlew -Dorg.gradle.project.publish.prune=true publish # won't publish
 *   $ gradlew -Dorg.gradle.project.publish.prune=false publish # will publish
 */
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each { task ->
        def pruned = shouldPrune(task)

        if (pruned) {
            recursivelyApplyToTaskDependencies(task) { p ->
                p.enabled = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```